# How to get a list in below format?

Tags: python, list

I have the following data in a text file.

```
22882367 /pgc-orc-hive-output 
13454914 /pqs 
2254110952 /processed-nrt-export 
..etc
```

Need to output as below format of array list

```
#[[22882367,'/' ,'pgc-orc-hive-output'],[13454914,'/','pqs'],[2254110952,'/','processed-nrt-export']]
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Do you need to read from txt. file? How does the data organized in file? tap-delimited?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You can't paste your problem and just let other users resolve it for you. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page to understand how to write a good question.

Comment: @Antwane: While theoretically what you say is true, in reality it happens here all the time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strip` and `split` as below to get the value separated as you want.

```
file = open('file.txt')
my_arr = []
for line in file:
    fields = line.strip().split()
    my_arr.append([fields[0], "/", fields[1][1:]])

print(my_arr)
```

Output:

```
[['22882367', '/', 'pgc-orc-hive-output'], ['13454914', '/', 'pqs'], ['2254110952', '/', 'processed-nrt-export']]
```

Comment: Maybe more readable using `.split(" /")` and then `my_arr.append([fields[0], "/", fields[1]])` ?

Comment: Working thanks,I was not getting how to append.I had tried the below code. with open('/tmp/hdfs_dir','r') as tsv:
  line = [elem.strip().split('\t') for elem in tsv]

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are expecting.

```
import re
fname= 'abcd.txt'

lists = []
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

for i in content:
    lists.append(re.split('(/)',i.strip()))


print lists
```

Comment: Getting output as expected,thnks